# Doxygen: document a class in the cpp file with separate source and header directories while using macros to define namespaces

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm trying to document a library with the following files:

```
include/mylib/mylib_global.h
include/mylib/SomeClass.h
source/SomeClass.cpp
Doxyfile
```

include/mylib/mylib_global.h:

```cpp
#pragma once
#define MYLIB_NAMESPACE_BEGIN namespace mylibns {
#define MYLIB_NAMESPACE_END   }
```

include/mylib/SomeClass.h:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "mylib_global.h"

MYLIB_NAMESPACE_BEGIN

class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass();
};

MYLIB_NAMESPACE_END
```

source/SomeClass.cpp:

```cpp
#include "mylib/SomeClass.h"

MYLIB_NAMESPACE_BEGIN

/*!
 * \class SomeClass
 * This is a sample class.
 */

/*!
 * This is a constructor.
 */
SomeClass::SomeClass()
{
}

MYLIB_NAMESPACE_END
```

Doxyfile:

```
PROJECT_NAME = mylib
INPUT = .
RECURSIVE = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION = YES
```

Doxygen produces the following warning:

```text
Doxygen version used: 1.9.3 (c0b9eafbfb53286ce31e75e2b6c976ee4d345473)
[...]
include/mylib/SomeClass.h:7: warning: Compound mylibns::SomeClass is not documented.
*** Doxygen has finished
```

If I do any of the following, it works:

- Move the cpp to `include/`. But I don't want it there.
- Move the documentation to the header. But I'd like to keep it short.
- `namespace mylibns {` instead of the macro in the cpp. But I want the namespace to be configurable.
- `MACRO_EXPANSION = NO`. But that would also remove the namespace from the documentation.
- Explicitly state the namespace in the doxygen comment: `\class mylibns::SomeClass`. However that only helps with this specific issue (doxygen also fails to resolve overloaded functions).

Things that don't help:

- Specifying any combination of longer paths for the `INPUT` parameter.
- `EXTRACT_ALL = YES`
- `CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING = YES`

How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file `source/SomeClass.cpp` you have:

```
#include "mylib/SomeClass.h"
```

but the file `SomeClass.h` is located in `include/mylib` so you have to tell doxygen where to find the include file. This can be done by means of the setting:

```
INCLUDE_PATH = include
```

(analogous what you probably have done for the compiler with the setting like `-I include`)